# PrintOut prints groups of sheets instead of 1 group

Tags: vba, excel, printing, excel-2007

We have this problem on many workbooks where we select a few sheets with VBA and print them using the following line and Excel will actually print multiple *groups* of pages instead of 1 group of multiple pages.

`ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut`

Here is an example of a `Sub` that has this behaviour:

```
Private Sub imprimer(iColTypeRapport As Integer)
    Dim cell As range, rangeImpr As range, colonne As range
    Dim debute As Boolean ' True seulement si on a déjà sélectionné une feuille

    On Error GoTo erreur

    application.ScreenUpdating = False

    debute = False
    Set rangeImpr = ActiveSheet.range("impression")
    Set colonne = rangeImpr.Offset(0, iColTypeRapport).EntireColumn

    For Each cell In rangeImpr
        If LCase(Intersect(cell.EntireRow, colonne)) = "o" Then
            If Not debute Then
                Worksheets(cell.Value).Select
                debute = True
            Else
                Worksheets(cell.Value).Select False
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

    Worksheets("TableauDeBord").Select
    application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

erreur:
    Call GestionErreur(Err.Number, Err.Description, "modRequete", "ImportData")
End Sub
```

This is made even more obvious if we use Print2PDF or AdobePDF print as it will prompt multiple times (in this case, 3 times) for file names.

If I put a breakpoint before PrintOut the sheets are selected appropriately and I see nothing unusual / unexpected.

Any idea ?

Comment: If you select and print them from the Excel interface do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Go to the regular print interface. Do you perhaps have the thingy set to print 3 copies?

Comment: Yes I do ! It does not seem to occur because of discontinuous sheet selection (which was my first guess) but I can't figure out why there are groups of pages. In this instance, there is even a page that is printed on its own (i.e. group of 1). I checked that they all have the same format and they do.

Comment: So, the groupings don't correspond to sheets?

Comment: Yes they do but I see no reason why some sheets are isolated.

Comment: I've seen this. It can have to do with things like different print resolutions. If you search on "print workbook produces multiple pdfs" you'll find some answers. With the PDF problem specifically, it can be resolved (in XL 2010 and, I'm guessing, 2007) by doing a "Save As" to PDF instead.

Comment: I concur with @DougGlancy, I've had the same issue.  Doug, want to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this. It can have to do with things like different print resolutions. If you search on "print workbook produces multiple pdfs" you'll find some answers. With the PDF problem specifically, it can be resolved (in XL 2010 and, I'm guessing, 2007) by doing a "Save As" to PDF instead.

Comment: Or of course you can make all the sheets the same resolution.